# mix data in very different formats

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes.
In the first one I have the hotel opening periods: "1" below the month means that the hotel is open, "0" that the hotel is closed.

```
hotels <- data.frame(
hotel = c (1:5), jan = c(1,1,1,0,0), feb = c(1,1,1,1,1), 
mar = c(1,1,1,1,1), ap = c(0,0,1,1,1), may = c(0,0,0,0,0),
jun = c(0,0,0,0,0), jul = c(0,0,0,1,1), aug = c(1,1,1,1,1),
sep = c(1,1,1,0,0), oct = c(0,0,0,1,1), nov = c(1,1,1,1,1),
des = c(1,1,1,1,1)
)
```

The second dataframe belongs to the clients, where we have the arrival and departure of said clients to the hotels.

```
clientes<-data.frame(
  id_client = c("a","b","c","d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), 
  hotel = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
  arrive = c("2019-01-08", "2019-05-04", "2019-06-25", "2019-11-24", "2019-03-04", "2019-06-01", "2019-05-04","2019-08-13", "2019-04-06", "2019-07-17"),
  departure = c("2019-01-10", "2019-05-08", "2019-07-05", "2019-12-01", "2019-03-08", "2019-06-09", "2019-05-10","2019-08-20", "2019-04-10", "2019-08-3")
  )
```

We want to know which clients have told the truth and which have not. If the dates do not match the overture period of the hotel, the client has not been honest.
Therefore we will want a dataframe like this answer:

```
results<-data.frame(
  id_client = c("a","b","c","d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), 
  hotel = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
  arrive = c("2019-01-08", "2019-05-04", "2019-06-25", "2019-11-24", "2019-03-04", "2019-06-01", "2019-05-04","2019-08-13", "2019-04-06", "2019-07-17"),
  honest = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `mapply` would be to extract the month `departure` and `arrive` columns. Pass this with `hotel` id to `mapply`, subset the relevant hotel from this info and check if the values have 1 for `all` the months client stayed in hotel.

```
clientes$departure <- as.Date(clientes$departure)
clientes$arrive <- as.Date(clientes$arrive)


clientes$honest <- mapply(function(x, y, z) 
 all(hotels[hotels$hotel == x, c(y, z)] == 1), clientes$hotel, 
    format(clientes$arrive, "%b"), format(clientes$departure, "%b"))


clientes
#   id_client hotel     arrive  departure honest
#1          a     1 2019-01-08 2019-01-10   TRUE
#2          b     2 2019-05-04 2019-05-08  FALSE
#3          c     3 2019-06-25 2019-07-05  FALSE
#4          d     4 2019-11-24 2019-12-01   TRUE
#5          e     5 2019-03-04 2019-03-08   TRUE
#6          f     1 2019-06-01 2019-06-09  FALSE
#7          g     2 2019-05-04 2019-05-10  FALSE
#8          h     3 2019-08-13 2019-08-20   TRUE
#9          i     4 2019-04-06 2019-04-10   TRUE
#10         j     5 2019-07-17 2019-08-03   TRUE
```

For this solution to work you need to do some changes to your dataset. The column names in your `hotel` dataset should be same as `month.abb` on your system so that they can be matched. I changed them manually here.

**data**

```
hotels <- data.frame(
  hotel = c (1:5), Jan = c(1,1,1,0,0), Feb = c(1,1,1,1,1), 
  Mar = c(1,1,1,1,1), Apr = c(0,0,1,1,1), May = c(0,0,0,0,0),
  Jun = c(0,0,0,0,0), Jul = c(0,0,0,1,1), Aug = c(1,1,1,1,1),
  Sep = c(1,1,1,0,0), Oct = c(0,0,0,1,1), Nov = c(1,1,1,1,1),
  Dec = c(1,1,1,1,1))

clientes<-data.frame(
id_client = c("a","b","c","d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), 
 hotel = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
  arrive = c("2019-01-08", "2019-05-04", "2019-06-25", "2019-11-24", "2019-03-04", 
  "2019-06-01", "2019-05-04","2019-08-13", "2019-04-06", "2019-07-17"),
departure = c("2019-01-10", "2019-05-08", "2019-07-05", "2019-12-01","2019-03-08", 
  "2019-06-09", "2019-05-10","2019-08-20", "2019-04-10", "2019-08-03"))
```